# Gradient of a line using Pythagora's theorem

Tags: geometry

I've been trying to solve a question but I am having some difficulties.

See the below diagram. I also know that the gradient of line c is twice as high as b i.e. c rises twice as fast as b.

[image: Diagram]

Question: what is the gradient of b and c? Can I work this out from the available information? I think it is a mix of Pythagora's theorem and knowing that the sum of all angles in a triangle is 180 degrees.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You can get the length of $a$ because it is the hypotenuse of a right triangle where the other two sides are of length $30$ and $15$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 I realise that. It's the gradient of lines b and c I am interested in.

Comment: Hint: call $(x,72)$ the point at the intersection of segments $b$ and $c$. Then you can write down the gradient of $b$ using the rise-over-run formula; similarly, you can write down the gradient of $c$. Setting the latter equal to twice the former and solving for $x$ will give you the crucial piece of information for answering everything about this picture.

Comment: @GregMartin Great, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

grad(c) is twice grad(b)

$\frac{84 - 72}{30 - x} = 2*\frac{72 - 69}{x - 0}$

$\frac{12}{30 - x} = 2*\frac{3}{x}$

$12x = 180 - 6x$

$18x = 180$

$x = 10$

Then you can compute the grads:

grad(b) =$\frac{3}{10}$

grad(c) =$\frac{12}{20}$=$\frac{6}{10}$

Comment: $84 - 72 = 6 ?$

Comment: yes @Dillon that's the computational mistakes in which I am not the best at all :) , do you have other complaints? about the method if possible

Comment: Hehe! No problem :). It's a very small mistake - arithmetic errors can occur very easily :) . The rest of your method seems perfect! :) Well done :)

Comment: hhhhhh I got it! it's all because we've beaten you 3-1 in the can2015? :P

Comment: Haha!! :'D . That doesn't bother me too much, to be honest :). Our football team is pretty much always terrible :P . I upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x,72)$ be the point of intersection of lines $b$ and $c$.

We will denote the gradient of lines $b$ and $c$ by $m_b$ and $m_c$ respectively.

Then we can find $$m_b = \frac{72 - 69}{x-0} = \frac{3}{x}$$

Now we know $$m_c = 2m_b = \frac{6}{x}$$

But we can also find that $$m_c = \frac{84 - 72}{30 - x} = \frac{12}{30-x}$$

Thus we must have that \begin{align}\frac{6}{x} = \frac{12}{30-x} \iff 6(30-x) &=12x \\\implies 180 - 6x &= 12x \\ \implies 180 &= 18x \\ \implies x &= 10\end{align}

Substituting back, we can then easily find that $$m_b = \frac{3}{10}$$ and $$m_c = \frac{12}{20} = \frac{3}{5}$$